Expo-AV causing problem "Accessed on wrong thread"
I am using Audio from expo-av, created a custom hook for playing Background music in-app, and using the playBGM function in Home.js
Everything works fine, BGM plays but the issue happening is, that it throws an error in the app not in the terminal and the error is 
I wasted 4 days searching and solving the problem but nothing helped:
here are versions of the packages:
"expo": "~51.0.17",
"expo-av": "~14.0.6",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.3",

And this is the code:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import { Platform } from "react-native";

const useSoundEffects = () => {
  const soundObjects = useRef({
    start: new Audio.Sound(),
    lost: new Audio.Sound(),
    finish: new Audio.Sound(),
    hint: new Audio.Sound(),
    touch: new Audio.Sound(),
    keypress: new Audio.Sound(),
    bgm: new Audio.Sound(),
  });

  const soundLoaded = useRef({
    start: false,
    lost: false,
    finish: false,
    hint: false,
    touch: false,
    keypress: false,
    bgm: false,
  });

  const loadSound = async (soundObject, soundName, soundFile) => {
    try {
      await soundObject.loadAsync(soundFile);
      soundLoaded.current[soundName] = true;
      if (soundName === "bgm") {
        await soundObject.setIsLoopingAsync(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error loading ${soundName} sound:`, error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadSounds = async () => {
      const { start, lost, finish, hint, touch, keypress, bgm } =
        soundObjects.current;

      await loadSound(start, "start", require("../../assets/sounds/start.mp3"));
      await loadSound(lost, "lost", require("../../assets/sounds/lost.mp3"));
      await loadSound(
        finish,
        "finish",
        require("../../assets/sounds/finish.mp3")
      );
      await loadSound(hint, "hint", require("../../assets/sounds/hint.mp3"));
      await loadSound(touch, "touch", require("../../assets/sounds/touch.mp3"));
      await loadSound(
        keypress,
        "keypress",
        require("../../assets/sounds/keypress.mp3")
      );
      await loadSound(bgm, "bgm", require("../../assets/sounds/bgm.mp3"));
    };

    loadSounds();

    return () => {
      Object.values(soundObjects.current).forEach(async (sound) => {
        await sound.unloadAsync();
      });
    };
  }, []);

  const runOnMainThread = (callback) => {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      callback();
    } else {
      setTimeout(callback, 0);
    }
  };

  const playSound = async (soundName, muteSounds) => {
    if (muteSounds) return;
    try {
      const soundObject = soundObjects.current[soundName];
      if (soundLoaded.current[soundName]) {
        runOnMainThread(async () => {
          await soundObject.replayAsync();
        });
      } else {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (soundLoaded.current[soundName]) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            runOnMainThread(async () => {
              await soundObject.replayAsync();
            });
          }
        }, 100);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error playing ${soundName} sound:`, error);
    }
  };

  const playBGM = async () => {
    try {
      const bgm = soundObjects.current.bgm;
      if (soundLoaded.current.bgm) {
        runOnMainThread(async () => {
          await bgm.playAsync();
        });
      } else {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (soundLoaded.current.bgm) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            runOnMainThread(async () => {
              await bgm.playAsync();
            });
          }
        }, 100);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error playing BGM:", error);
    }
  };

  const stopBGM = async () => {
    try {
      const bgm = soundObjects.current.bgm;
      const status = await bgm.getStatusAsync();
      if (status.isPlaying) {
        runOnMainThread(async () => {
          await bgm.stopAsync();
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error stopping BGM:", error);
    }
  };

  return {
    playSound,
    playBGM,
    stopBGM,
  };
};

export default useSoundEffects;



i have same problem to no solution yet

the official expo-av is not compatible enough I think.
